# Support JAX-RS 2.0 with WebLogic 12C

Tags: java, spring, jax-rs, weblogic

I am reading the following links to get weblogic suported Jaxrs 2.0

https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1213/wls/WLUPG/upgrade_ws.htm#WLUPG332 
https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1213/wls/RESTF/use-jersey20-ri.htm#RESTF297

I have found javax.ws.rs-api-2.0.jar file renamed it javax.ws.rs-api-2.0.war.
Then deploy it as a library file into weblogic.

But I am still having the error since weblogic still use jaxrs 1.1 APIs.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'openStackService': Invocation of init method failed;
hodError: javax.ws.rs.core.MultivaluedMap.addAll(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)V
```

here is my all configuration:

**pom.xml**

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
        <version>2.10.1</version>
    </dependency> 

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.pacesys</groupId>
            <artifactId>openstack4j</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.9</version>
        </dependency>
```

**weblogic.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wls:weblogic-web-app xmlns:wls="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app 
           http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app/1.7/weblogic-web-app.xsd">

    <context-root>jaxrsrest</context-root>
    <wls:library-ref> 
       <library-name>javax.ws.rs</library-name>
       <specification-version>2.0</specification-version>
       <exact-match>false</exact-match>
    </wls:library-ref>
</wls:weblogic-web-app>
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have realized that weblogic 12.1.3 comes with following foldes having jax-rs-2.0.war

Oracle\wlserver\common\deployable-libraries.

I have installed the war file as library into Application Server